# How does NodeJS process incoming requests

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I have been studying and doing hands-on practice with NodeJS since few weeks now.

I understand that it is a single-threaded, event based, javascript runtime environment.
It uses an event loop to process javascript statements and any incoming IO requests from clients.

But I am getting a hard time understanding that when a request comes to NodeJS from an external client like ReactJS or Postman. How it reaches the event loop and in which phase of event loop does it get processed. So far I have read many articles which go on repeating the same thing about various phases but I am not convinced whether my understanding of how request is handled by NodeJS is correct.

So here is my understanding:

1. NodeJS listens on a port for any incoming requests
2. When a client sends the request to that port, then the request is picked up by NodeJS
3. Now it goes to Event Queue and waits there until it gets picked up in the Poll phase by the event loop

Also there are a couple of doubts I have around my understanding:

1. I know that we setup various routes in our node app that trigger certain logic when a request comes in. But at what point/phase does NodeJS do this route matching of incoming requests.
2. What happens after event loop picks up a request from Event Queue? How does it get processed by the V8 engine?